# Are there any studies on the relationship between software testing practices and developer productivity?

Tags: productivity, testing, unit-testing, research, integration-tests

Are there any studies on the relationship between software testing practices (unit and/or integration tests) and developer productivity?

Answer (score 6):

[Making Software: What Really Works, and Why We Believe It](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596808321) has a chapter on TDD (now TDD is not what you were asking for, but this is the only credible book I know of to mention unit-testing in any shape or form).

[image]